# Are dual numbers a special case of grassmann numbers?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, hypercomplex-numbers

[Dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) are defined in analogy to complex numbers like
$$
z = a + \varepsilon b.
$$
But instead of $i^2=-1$ it is defined that $\varepsilon^2=0$.

The multiplication rule for [Grassmann numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) $\theta_i$ is
$$
\theta_i\theta_j = - \theta_j \theta_i
$$
so that $\theta_i\theta_i = 0$.

So it seem that dual numbers are just a special case of a Grassmann algebra with just one generator ($i = j = 1$). Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. By the way, both of these are also what mathematicians call an [exterior algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the dual numbers are isomorphic to the Clifford algebra $\mathcal{Cl}_{0,0,1}$ with one imaginary element.